# How can I call these urls in jquery to display content on one page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

ok I figured out the jquery part but not the parameters of them all can anyone help figure out the parameters for each url string?

this is the jquery I figured out!
also would this work better then what the below answer?

> $.get('adminajax.php', {'action':'getUsers'}, function(data){
>   $('#users .users').html(data);
>   });

He sent me this in an email:

> You can specify a page by adding: p=[page #] You can specify a file
>   and it will add a checkbox next to the user which will be checked if
>   the user has permission to download: file=[file location]
>
> adminajax.php?action=createDirectory&directory=[new directory location]
>
> adminajax.php?action=setAvailability&user=[username]&file=[filelocation]&available=[true or false]

I'm trying to get it to display in these html tags:

```
<div id="files">
    <b>Files:</b>
    <ul class="files"></ul>
</div>

<div id="file_options">
    <b>Options:</b>
</div>

<div id="users">
    <b>Users:</b>
    <ul class="users"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: start by opening the get directories link in browser, copy and paste output into this question so people can see what data structure is like. Assuming it is json can run it through jsonlint.com to format it for readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is Ajax call. Here's an example:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'GET',
  url:'adminajax.php',
  data: {action:'getDirectory', directory:'directoryNameHere'},
  success: function (response) {
    //here the response is the stuff that the server replied with
    var json = $.parseJSON(response); //if the server returned JSON you need to parse it
    //do stuff with that data
  } 
});
```

This is the code for the first example to get files. Adjust accordingly for other examples.

The server response should be available in the success function. Try to console it out to see what you got from it, if it's JSON it needs to be parsed first.

Url seems to be the same for all examples, only the action and other parameters are changing, so for other calls you only need to change the data properety of the ajax call.

For getting users your data object would be just action, there are no other parameters:

```
data: {action: 'getUsers'}
```

For creating a directory:

```
data: {action:'createDirectory', directory: 'nameOfDirectoryHere'}
```

As charlietfl noted in the comments, you don't need to do $.parseJSON if you put dataType: 'json' in the ajax call. (If the data is JSON of course).

Comment: oh ok! thank you for the fast response, would I do this for any of the urls? also I know nothing about ajax still new to all the coding :D im good with the html and css that's about it haha @tomca32

Comment: Well as you can see the url itself goes in the url proprety. Action part of the url goes into action property of data, and for any other parameter you see in the url, you make a parameter in the data object.

Comment: Edited my answer with additional explanation

Comment: use `dataType:'json` for ajax request and don't need to use `$.parseJSON(response);` as $.ajax will do conversion internally

Comment: ok so I put the script in my code as printed and got nothing am I doing something wrong? also should I replace var json = $.parseJSON(response); with dataType:'json'? @tomca32

Comment: put console.log(response); right before it and take a look at the developer console to see what are you getting back.